# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log_2 x)^3}{x^n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

> I need help with proving the following $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left({\log}_2x\right)^3}{x^n}=0\ , \quad \forall n>0.$$

I used wolframalpha and got it

[image]

and I had kind of an intuition because of the limit $\frac{\ln(x)}x$ , and still I have no idea how to formaly proof it.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac {\ln x} {x^{n/3}}$

Comment: Thanks al lot!
Can you please help me to understand why would it prove the limit I asked for?

Comment: If $f(x) \to 0$ then $(f(x))^{3}$ also $\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks!
Sorry for my next stupid question , but why can I just replace log2 with ln?

Comment: I could have used $\log_2$. It makes litle difference because $\log_2 x= \frac {\ln x} {\ln 2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint of @Kavi Rama Murthy, note that $$f(x)\to 0 \implies f^{3}(x)\to 0$$
In your problem, you can define that $f(x):=\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{x^{n/3}}$ so, by L'Hospital's Rule you can find that $$\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{x^{n/3}} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad x \to \infty$$
So, by the hint and since that $f^{3}(x)=\frac{\log_{2}^{3}(x)}{x^{n}}$ so $$\frac{\log_{2}^{3}(x)}{x^{n}} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad x\to \infty$$
this's true for all $n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

### HINT

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left({\log}_2{x}\right)^3}{x^n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t\left(\ln{x}\right)^3}{x^n}$$
where $t=\ln^32$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t\left(1-\frac1x\right)^3}{x^n}\le\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t\left(\ln x\right)^3}{x^n}\le\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t\left(x-1\right)^3}{x^n}$$

$$\to0\le\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{t\left(\ln x\right)^3}{x^n}\le\to0$$

Now the limit is obvious from squeeze theorem.

For the inequality, refer [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm)

Here's a convincing graph:
[image]

Comment: Cool! but does it apply to any positive n? I mean if n=1 so right side doesn't apply, isn't it?

Comment: Good observation! The upper bound tends to 0 for only n>3. I'm trying to give you a bound for n<3 as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct way without L'Hospital:

Substituting $x=e^t$ and using $\log_2 x= \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$ you have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\log_2 x)^3}{x^n} =\frac 1{\ln^3 2}\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t^3}{e^{nt}}$$

Now, since $e^u = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^k}{k!}$, you have $e^u > \frac{u^4}{4!}$ for any $u>0$. Hence,

$$0\leq \frac{t^3}{e^{nt}} < \frac{t^3}{\frac{(nt)^4}{4!}}=\frac{4!}{n^4}\cdot \frac 1t \stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $K,L$ are positive and $B>1$ then, with $C=1/\ln B$, we have (for $x>1$)$$\frac {(\log_Bx)^K}{x^L}=\frac {(C\ln x)^K}{x^L}=\frac {(C\ln x)^K}{(x^{L/K})^K}=$$ $$=\frac {(\,C(K/L)\ln (x^{L/K})\,)^K}{(x^{L/K})^K}=$$ $$=C^K(K/L)^K\left(\frac {\ln (x^{L/K})}{x^{L/K}}\right)^K.$$